# CKEditor with jQuery output is chopped, possibly because of special characters

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, special-characters

I have the following code that correctly generates the CKEditor:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#newWrite_body").ckeditor({
                                 extraPlugins : 'autogrow',
                                 autoGrow_maxHeight : 800});
});
</script>
```

Then I grab some text from a web page, paste it into the editor, and alert the text back upon submitting it shows:

```
<p>
    <b>Fort McKay, Alberta (CNN)</b> -- Celina Harpe was 7 when her grandfather 
       made a prediction that would forever change her life.</p>
<p>
    &quot;I won&#39;t see it, I&#39;m too old now, but it&#39;s going to be 
    really bad,&quot; she recalls him saying on a warm summer night after 
    returning from a moose hunt. The two were standing on a hill that overlooks 
    the birch-and-spruce-lined river here in far northwest Canada.</p>
```

But when I `echo` it back from the PHP code before the insert, it is reduced to:

```
<p>
    <b>Fort McKay, Alberta (CNN)</b> -- Celina Harpe was 7 when her grandfather 
    made a prediction that would forever change her life.</p>
<p>
```

Apparently the special characters are being dropped. All my attempts to escape them and/or convert them have been futile.

What is the proper way to convert these from CKEditor's text to a POST-able value in PHP?

Comment: To discount the special chars. Try adding a special char at the beginng of the text and pasting that in. How much do you get back then? Also is this CKeditor being submitted via AJAX or through a traditional web form?

Comment: I finally found the answer.  There is a Javascript built-in function called "escape".  So this worked:  var text = escape(str).  And this is with ajax.

Comment: Post your answer and accept it. This will correctly mark this question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. There is a Javascript built-in function called "escape". So this worked:

```
var text = escape(str);
// THEN POST STRING VIA AJAX
```

And this is with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There's a config setting inside ckEditor called **CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput**

That may be what you want.

[ckEditor Configuration Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html)